# Tensorflow function tf.image.crop_and_resize is not working as expected

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, computer-vision

I have the next snippet of code.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.misc import imread
import tensorflow
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = imread('dog.jpg')
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()

h, w, _ = img.shape

cnr = tensorflow.image.crop_and_resize(np.expand_dims(img, 0), np.array([[0., 0.5, 0., 0.5]]), [0], (h/2, w/2))
plt.imshow(img[0:h/2, 0:w/2, :])
plt.show()

with tensorflow.Session() as sess:
    a = sess.run(cnr)
    plt.imshow(a[0])
    plt.show()
```

If I understand the method `crop_and_resize`correctly, the first `plt.imshow` should show the original image and the next two calls should show the same portion of the image, since I am cropping the image and resizing to the same shape (so not resizing should be taking place here).

However, the last call to `plt.show` only shows a purple image.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does anyone why is this not working as expected?

Answer (score 0):

The actual order should be `[y1, x1, y2, x2]` as stated in the [TF documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/crop_and_resize). Keep in mind that the `x` increases from left to right as usual, but the `y` increases from top to bottom instead of bottom to top. For example if you want to divide an image in four equal parts, one for each of its four corners, then you do the following:

```
height = int(h/4)
width = int(w/4)
top_left = tf.image.crop_and_resize(img, boxes=[[0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.5]], 
    crop_size=[height, width], box_ind=[0])
top_right = tf.image.crop_and_resize(img, boxes=[[0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0]], 
    crop_size=[height, width], box_ind=[0])
bottom_left = tf.image.crop_and_resize(img, boxes=[[0.5, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5]], 
    crop_size=[height, width], box_ind=[0])
bottom_right = tf.image.crop_and_resize(img, boxes=[[0.5, 0.5, 1.0, 1.0]], 
    crop_size=[height, width], box_ind=[0])
```

Answer (score -1):

Nevermind, the second argument of the function should be in the form (x1, y1, x2, y2) not (x1, x2, y1, y2) as spotted in the question

Comment: see my answer below